# Understanding perspective transform in 3D Core Animation

Tags: ios, 3d, core-animation

I’m trying to create a view consisting of several 3D cube’s viewed from a center perspective of the containing view.

When I set a cube view as a direct subview of the container view and then set the perspective as follows;

```
var perspective = CATransform3DIdentity
perspective.m34 = -1.0/250
containerView.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective
```

The 3d perspective transform works as expected. However, if I first add the cube view to a innerContainerView and then add that to the parent container view the perspective is lost. I [created a playground](https://github.com/Sully73/3Dperspective) to illustrate my problem.

```
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 667.0, height: 375.0))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = containerView

let green = UIColor.greenColor()
let blue = UIColor.blueColor()
let red = UIColor.redColor()
let purple = UIColor.purpleColor()
let yellow = UIColor.yellowColor()
let orange = UIColor.orangeColor()


var perspective = CATransform3DIdentity
perspective.m34 = -1.0/250
containerView.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective

let cubeView1 = CubeView(frontColor: green, backColor: blue, topColor: red, rightColor: purple, bottomColor: yellow, leftColor: orange)
cubeView1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)
let innerContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 200))
innerContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
containerView.addSubview(innerContainerView)
innerContainerView.addSubview(cubeView1)


let cubeView2 = CubeView(frontColor: green, backColor: blue, topColor: red, rightColor: purple, bottomColor: yellow, leftColor: orange)
cubeView2.frame = CGRectMake(400, 200, 100, 100)
containerView.addSubview(cubeView2)
```

[image: Playground image]

I'm trying to create the same perspective shown in the right cube in the left cube. So why is it when I add the an intermediate view I lose the perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreAnimaton rendering model always flattens rendering operations on to the parent layer. The one exception to this rule is `CATransformLayer` which doesn't do any flattening and just passes the transforms through. Creating a `UIView` with `CATransformLayer` as the  `layerClass` and using that as `innerContainerView` should solve the issue.